# Linear map and its chaining

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a task:

We have defined two linear maps

$A: R^{2} -> R^{2}$

$B: R^{2} -> R^{2}$

And we know that

$A(1,1) = (-1,2)$

$A(0,1) = (-3,-6)$

and

$B(x1,x2) = ( 9x1, - 6x2, 6x1 - 4x2)$

And we are to create linear map such as

$C = A * B$ and $D = B * A$ and find their matrices with respect to Unit base.

What i have done so far: We can interpret base of A as X and base of B as Y

in order to create $C$ we can do $C = E^{e->y} * A^{x -> e}$

and to create D we can do $D = E^{ e -> x } * B^{y -> e }$

To create matrix of linear map A we can do this

$A^{X -> e}\begin{pmatrix} -1 & -3 \\ -2 & -6 \\ \end{pmatrix}$

To create matrix of linear map B we can do this

$B^{Y -> e}\begin{pmatrix} 9 & 6 \\ -6 & -4 \\ \end{pmatrix}$

create C is quite easy if i get it right

$D = E^{e -> Y} * B^{y -> e} = (E^{Y -> e } )^{-1} * B^{Y ->e} $

= $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}^{-1}$ * $\begin{pmatrix} 9 & 6 \\ -6 & -4 \\ \end{pmatrix}$

But what about the D? I am not sure if i expressed the map B with right matrices and the lack of number and pressence of variables( x1... xn) quite confuses me.

What is the rigth way to solve problem like this? I higly appreciate all help.